# Ruby singleton from stdlib. How to kill an instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning ruby and this is the case I have.

```
require 'singleton'
class Lab
  include Singleton
  def initialize
    puts 'initializing'
  end
end

l1 = Lab.instance
l2 = Lab.instance
```

Even though I have done Lab.instance twice I get the message "initializing" only once. That means singleton is working. Great!

Rails in development mode kills all the constants using const_remove so that on next request models and controllers are reloaded.

I want to try something similar here. I want to kill both l1 and l2 so that when I do Lab.instance a new instance is created and I get the message "initializing".

Is there a way to achieve what I am asking for?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Singleton mix-in uses a fairly simple mechanism you can easily re-implement. If you take a look at its core, you'll see that it uses an instance variable named `@singleton__instance__` for caching. Thus,  resetting this variable should do the job. Thus, if you try to add this class method to your class:

```
def self.reset
    @singleton__instance__ = nil
end
```

You can do:

```
l1 = Lab.instance #=> initializing
l2 = Lab.instance #=> nothing
Lab.reset
l3 = Lab.instance #=> initializing
l4 = Lab.instance  #=> nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just an idea, but how about implementing your own singleton module?

```
module MyLittleSingleton
  def instance(*args, &block)
    @instance ||= new(*args, &block)
  end
  def reload_instance!
    @instance = nil
  end
end

class Lab
  extend MyLittleSingleton
end
```

It won't provide you with the same "safety" as the normal Singleton, but it might be just what you need.

Comment: rolling your own stuff is always there as the last resort. Thanks for the suggestion and for the code example.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a brand new instance of your singleton (for example, to play with it during a test without affecting other tests), you can use an anonymous subclass:

```
Lab.instance    # This writes "initializing"

MyLab = Class.new(Lab)

MyLab.instance  # This writes "initializing"
MyLab.instance  # This writes nothing
```

If you **really** want to reset your singleton, you can do the following but you enter the *warning zone*, it's not part of public API:

```
Lab.instance    # This writes "initializing"

# Do it at your own risks
Singleton.__init__(Lab)

Lab.instance    # This writes "initializing"
Lab.instance    # This writes nothing
```